# component.find in the component inside the promise functions of workspaceAPI methods getEnclosingTabId() while handling the event lightning;tabClosed

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using lightning console event 'tabClosed' (lightning:tabClosed)
Inside it, I am getting the current tab Id using getEnclosingTabId method present in the workspaceAPI. inside promise methods, I try to access the component values using 'find' method via aura:id, then It is throwing undefined. Is this due to closure of the tab so reference to component is not available? Is there any other approach how to get the value from component inside the promise method of this 'getEnclosingTabId' method while calling console event lightning:tabClosed

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/361466/edit) your question to add your code text and the exact error text. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include...(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form).")*

Answer (score 0):

As the event is being raised inside `tabCloseEvent`, the tab's component is already destroyed in the `resolve` or `reject` phase of the promise function. Thus all the variables inside it will return undefined.
You can try one thing, fetch you `find` variable before you fire the `getEnclosingTabId`.

```
onTabClosed : function(component, event, helper){
    let workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    // try fetching you find here instead of inside .then method
    workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId().then(function(tabId) {
        console.log(tabId);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```